# cannot combine \foreach and \draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

I just cannot debug this code.  After typesetting it keeps on giving the error of: "Undefined Control Sequence"
When individually coding rectangles for each set of coordinates the code works though, but it is nonetheless cumbersome...
What am I missing with \foreach and \draw ???

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 10,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 10,
        ]
        \foreach \linker / \regter in {{(1,1) / (2,2)}, {(2,2) / (3,3)},{(3,3)/(4,4)}} {
                \edef\temp{\draw[thick] \linker rectangle \regter;
                }
                \temp
            }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can move the `\draw` outside of the `\foreach` and then you do not need to use the expansion:

[image]

### Notes:

- Normally one would need to use `axis cs:` coordinate system *within* an `axis` environment. But, as  Manuel commented, in pgfplots version 1.11 this is now the default coordinate system. So, if using a version *prior* to `1.11` each coordinate needs to be specified as

  ```
      \foreach \linker / \regter in {
          {(axis cs:1,1) / (axis cs:2,2)}, 
          {(axis cs:2,2) / (axis cs:3,3)},
          {(axis cs:3,3) / (axis cs:4,4)}} 
              {
                  \linker rectangle \regter
              };
  ```

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin = -1,
        xmax = 10,
        ymin = -1,
        ymax = 10,
        ]
        \draw[thick,blue] 
            \foreach \linker / \regter in {
                {(1,1) / (2,2)}, 
                {(2,2) / (3,3)},
                {(3,3) / (4,4)} } 
                    {
                        \linker rectangle \regter
                    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but I think “for some reason it does not seem to be necessary in this case” is because that's how it works in the last version. I'm out TikZ/pgfplots world, but I think I read that now you don't need `axis cs` because it's the new way it works.

Comment: @Manuel: Thanks. You are correct, that is indeed the default coordinate system within the `axis` environment with `pgfplots 1.11`.

Answer (score 6):

I guess your problem was commas. Commas separate tuples, so if you have a comma in one parameter, you should surround it by curly brackets. For me this code works.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
% \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 10,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 10,
    ]
  \end{axis}
  \foreach \linker / \regter in {%
    {(1,1)}/{(2,2)}, %
    {(2,2)}/{(3,3)}, %
    {(3,3)}/{(4,4)}%
  } { \draw[thick] \linker rectangle \regter; }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: My image is quite different.

Comment: Moving the `\draw` outside of the `axis` environment changes things considerably. Try, for instance, changing `xmin = -2` and you will see that the rectangles have not moved at all, even though the coordinates have. So, even though the drawing _almost_ looks correct in this case, it is not drawn at the desired coordinates.

Comment: From the commented line I'm guessing your pgfplots version is different.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in passing `\draw` to `\edef`; precede it with `\noexpand`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 10,
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 10,
]
\foreach \linker / \regter in {{(1,1) / (2,2)}, {(2,2) / (3,3)},{(3,3)/(4,4)}} {
   \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[thick] \linker rectangle \regter;}\temp
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see why the `\edef` was necessary. Shouldn't you be able to do the `\draw` directly?  Also, I think that the `axis cs` coordinate system should be specified when accessing coordinates within the `axis` environment.

Comment: @PeterGrill Compare with the other answer.

Comment: @PeterGrill If you don't use `\edef` pgfplots collects four copies of `\draw[thick] \linker rectangle \regter;` and expands when the visualization phase kicks in. And all instances expand to the same thing. TikZ on the other hand draws a path immediately instead of accumulating until the drawing commands are collected.